# What is the best way to accept a credit card in ASP.NET? (Between ASP.NET and Authorize.NET)

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, shopping-cart, credit-card, authorize.net

I'm new to creating commerce websites, and now that I need to sell software over the internet, I'm not sure where to start.

I'm using ASP.NET and am considering using Authorize.NET to validate and process the credit cards.

I'm looking for a stable, trusted solution that I can install on a single server.  My secondary goal (besides selling products online) is to become familiar with shopping cart software that is popular, and in use by large businesses.  Perhaps I should start with MS Commerce server?

Comment: Integrating with Authorize.Net is super easy.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million options here, but if you are writing the code, the easiest way code-wise is to use http://sharpauthorize.com/

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.Net is Very easy to implement with ASP.NET

Basically you can make transaction in 3-4 ways:

1. Simple Checkout Through Button like Paypal (http://developer.authorize.net/api/simplecheckout/)
2. Direct Post : Suppose you little bit more customization than Simple CheckOut. Create a checkout form that posts directly to Authorize.Net   http://developer.authorize.net/api/simplecheckout/

**Eg:**

```
<h1><%=ViewData["message"] %></h1>
<%using (Html.BeginSIMForm("http://YOUR_SERVER.com/home/sim",
1.99M,"YOUR_API_LOGIN","YOUR_TRANSACTION_KEY",true)){%>
<%=Html.CheckoutFormInputs(true)%>
<%=Html.Hidden("order_id","1234") %>
<input type = "submit" value = "Pay" />
<%}%>
```

1. SIM (Server Integration)
2. AIM (Advance Integration Method): Give full control & customization.
3. CIM ( store Customer card no & info on Auth.NET server with tokanization)

****Below is a sample of CIM function to make a transaction, AIM is very much similar to CIM only difference is tokanization*** *

```
using ProjName.AuthApiSoap;  // USE AUth Webserice Reference

   public Tuple<string, string, string> CreateTransaction(long profile_id, long payment_profile_id, decimal amt, string DDD)
        {
            CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransAuthCaptureType auth_capture = new CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransAuthCaptureType();
            auth_capture.customerProfileId = profile_id;
            auth_capture.customerPaymentProfileId = payment_profile_id;
            auth_capture.amount = amt;//1.00m;
            auth_capture.order = new CustomerProfileWS.OrderExType();
            POSLib.POSManager objManager = new POSLib.POSManager();
            auth_capture.order.invoiceNumber = objManager.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            auth_capture.order.description = "Service  " + DDD;
            CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransactionType trans = new CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransactionType();
            trans.Item = auth_capture;
            CustomerProfileWS.CreateCustomerProfileTransactionResponseType response = SoapAPIUtilities.Service.CreateCustomerProfileTransaction(SoapAPIUtilities.MerchantAuthentication, trans, null);

            string AuthTranMsg = "";
            string AuthTranCode = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < response.messages.Length; i++)
            {
                AuthTranMsg = response.messages[i].text;  // To Get Message n for loop to check the [i] is not empty 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < response.messages.Length; i++)
            {
                AuthTranCode = response.messages[i].code;   // To Get Code n for loop to check the [i] is not empty 
            }
            var tCompResp = new Tuple<string, string, string>(AuthTranCode, AuthTranMsg, response.directResponse);
            return tCompResp;
        }
```

**This is how to split the Reponse Msg  (Format and Order will be FIXED for all transaction/ on web service responsed )**

```
 var tResp = objManager.CreateTransaction(profID, paymProfID, Convert.ToDecimal(PmtToday), DDD);
                    string respCCNo = "";
                    string RespCCType = "";
                    string InvoiceNo = "";
                    string transType = "";
                    string approvalCode = "";
                    string AmtRequested = "";
                    string respName = "";
                    string respReasonText = "";
                    string respMD5Hash = "";
                    string respEmailId = "";
                    string respReasonCode = "";
                    string respMethod = "";
                    string respAVSResultCode = "";
                    string responseCode = "";
                    string transactionId = "0";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tCompResp.Item3))
                    {
                        string[] arrRespParts = tCompResp.Item3.Replace("|", "").Split(',');
                        responseCode = arrRespParts[0];
                        respReasonCode = arrRespParts[2];
                        respReasonText = arrRespParts[3];
                        approvalCode = arrRespParts[4];
                        respAVSResultCode = arrRespParts[5];
                        transactionId = arrRespParts[6].Replace("|", "");
                        InvoiceNo = arrRespParts[7];
                        AmtRequested = arrRespParts[9];
                        transType = arrRespParts[10];
                        respMethod = arrRespParts[11];
                        respName = arrRespParts[13] + " " + arrRespParts[14];
                        respEmailId = arrRespParts[23];
                        respMD5Hash = arrRespParts[37];
                        respCCNo = arrRespParts[50];
                        RespCCType = arrRespParts[51];
                    }
```

**==================================AIM Code**

```
 public Tuple<string, string, string> ECheckCreateTransAIM(string amount, string bankRoutingNo, string bankAccNo, string bankAccType, string bankName, string bankAccName, string echeckType, bool isCustomerEmail, string customerEmail, string mechantEMail)
        {
            //CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "";
            string AuthNetVersion = "3.1"; // Contains CCV support

            WebClient webClientRequest = new WebClient();
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection InputObject = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(30);
            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ReturnObject = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection(30);
            byte[] ReturnBytes;
            string[] ReturnValues;
            string ErrorString;
            InputObject.Add("x_version", AuthNetVersion);
            InputObject.Add("x_delim_data", "True");
            InputObject.Add("x_login", MERCHANT_NAME);
            InputObject.Add("x_tran_key", TRANSACTION_KEY);
            InputObject.Add("x_relay_response", "False");
            //----------------------Set to False to go Live--------------------
            InputObject.Add("x_test_request", "False");
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------
            InputObject.Add("x_delim_char", ",");
            InputObject.Add("x_encap_char", "|");
            if (isCustomerEmail)
            {
                InputObject.Add("x_email", customerEmail);
                InputObject.Add("x_email_customer", "TRUE");                     //Emails Customer
            }
            InputObject.Add("x_merchant_email", mechantEMail);
            // FOR echeck            
            InputObject.Add("x_bank_aba_code", bankRoutingNo);
            InputObject.Add("x_bank_acct_num", bankAccNo);
            InputObject.Add("x_bank_acct_type", bankAccType);
            InputObject.Add("x_bank_name", bankName);
            InputObject.Add("x_bank_acct_name", bankAccName);
            InputObject.Add("x_method", "ECHECK");
            InputObject.Add("x_type", "AUTH_CAPTURE");
            InputObject.Add("x_amount", string.Format("{0:c2}", Convert.ToDouble(amount)));
            // Currency setting. Check the guide for other supported currencies           
            //needto change it to Actual Server URL
            //Set above Testmode=off to go live
            webClientRequest.BaseAddress = eCheckBaseAddress;  //"https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx"; //"https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll";
            ReturnBytes = webClientRequest.UploadValues(webClientRequest.BaseAddress, "POST", InputObject);
            ReturnValues = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ReturnBytes).Split(",".ToCharArray());
            if (ReturnValues[0].Trim(char.Parse("|")) == "1")  // Succesful Transaction
            {
                //AuthNetCodeLabel.Text = ReturnValues[4].Trim(char.Parse("|")); // Returned Authorisation Code
                //AuthNetTransIDLabel.Text = ReturnValues[6].Trim(char.Parse("|")); // Returned Transaction ID
                var tCompResp = new Tuple<string, string, string>("I00001", ReturnValues[3].Trim(char.Parse("|")), string.Join(",", ReturnValues));
                return tCompResp;
            }
            else
            {
                // Error!
                ErrorString = ReturnValues[3].Trim(char.Parse("|")) + " (" + ReturnValues[2].Trim(char.Parse("|")) + ")";
                if (ReturnValues[2].Trim(char.Parse("|")) == "45")
                {
                    if (ErrorString.Length > 1)
                        ErrorString += "<br />n";

                    // AVS transaction decline
                    ErrorString += "Address Verification System (AVS) " +
                      "returned the following error: ";

                    switch (ReturnValues[5].Trim(char.Parse("|")))
                    {
                        case "A":
                            ErrorString += " the zip code entered does not match the billing address.";
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            ErrorString += " no information was provided for the AVS check.";
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            ErrorString += " a general error occurred in the AVS system.";
                            break;
                        case "G":
                            ErrorString += " the credit card was issued by a non-US bank.";
                            break;
                        case "N":
                            ErrorString += " neither the entered street address nor zip code matches the billing address.";
                            break;
                        case "P":
                            ErrorString += " AVS is not applicable for this transaction.";
                            break;
                        case "R":
                            ErrorString += " please retry the transaction; the AVS system was unavailable or timed out.";
                            break;
                        case "S":
                            ErrorString += " the AVS service is not supported by your credit card issuer.";
                            break;
                        case "U":
                            ErrorString += " address information is unavailable for the credit card.";
                            break;
                        case "W":
                            ErrorString += " the 9 digit zip code matches, but the street address does not.";
                            break;
                        case "Z":
                            ErrorString += " the zip code matches, but the address does not.";
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            var tCompRespFail = new Tuple<string, string, string>(ReturnValues[6].ToString(), ErrorString, string.Join(",", ReturnValues));
            return tCompRespFail;


        }
```

**CIM CODE (Tokanisation (Card not present method)**

```
   public Tuple<string, string, string> CreateTransaction(long profile_id, long payment_profile_id, decimal amt, string DDD)
        {
            CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransAuthCaptureType auth_capture = new CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransAuthCaptureType();
            auth_capture.customerProfileId = profile_id;
            auth_capture.customerPaymentProfileId = payment_profile_id;
            auth_capture.amount = amt;//1.00m;
            auth_capture.order = new CustomerProfileWS.OrderExType();
            POSLib.POSManager objManager = new POSLib.POSManager();
            auth_capture.order.invoiceNumber = objManager.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            auth_capture.order.description = "Service  " + DDD;
            CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransactionType trans = new CustomerProfileWS.ProfileTransactionType();
            trans.Item = auth_capture;
            CustomerProfileWS.CreateCustomerProfileTransactionResponseType response = SoapAPIUtilities.Service.CreateCustomerProfileTransaction(SoapAPIUtilities.MerchantAuthentication, trans, null);

            string AuthTranMsg = "";
            string AuthTranCode = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < response.messages.Length; i++)
            {
                AuthTranMsg = response.messages[i].text;  // To Get Message n for loop to check the [i] is not empty 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < response.messages.Length; i++)
            {
                AuthTranCode = response.messages[i].code;   // To Get Code n for loop to check the [i] is not empty 
            }
            var tCompResp = new Tuple<string, string, string>(AuthTranCode, AuthTranMsg, response.directResponse);
            return tCompResp;
        }
```